# responsive websites using playframework

Tags: playframework, responsive-design

Are the web applications created using play framework responsive? I want to create web apps whose UI elements (HTML) can adjust dynamically based on screen size. Would I need to use bootstrap with Play to make web applications responsive?

Definition of responsive websites
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Answer (score 1):

From the link (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

> Responsive Web Design is about using CSS and HTML to resize, hide,
>   shrink, enlarge, or move the content to make it look good on any
>   screen

`Responsiveness` is the ability of the client side and only client side. So yes - the web application created using Play Framework could be responsive if a developer creates responsive UI with HTML and CSS (and Javascript).

Play Framework does not have any special UI components (except some form parts, but it's just tiny helpers). You mention bootstrap in your question, so you can try the Play Framework library for Bootstrap: https://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/ (I did not use).

Comment: Bootstrap library from adrianhurt is really nice library, works perfectly with Play Forms.